# How to personalize \citeauthor command

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm writing thesis using tuned `report` class, biblatex and biber for bibliography.
`bib` file entries are generated by ScienceDirect export citation feature and style is czech-iso.

For referring to some figure, graph or table I'd like to get this layout:

> Image
>
> Caption
>
> From: 1st Author et.al.: Title [#].

and in bibliography

> [#] 1st AUTHOR, 2nd AUTHOR, 3rd AUTHOR, Title,...

For that purpose I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt%,draft%
 ]{report}
\usepackage[french,english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
babel=other,
sortlocale=cs_CZ,
style=iso-numeric,
autocite=superscript
]{biblatex}

\newcommand\foo[1]{\footnotesize{From: \Citeauthor{#1}: \citetitle{#1} \cite{#1}}}
\addbibresource{citace.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
image
\caption{Text}
\foo{Yoshizawa:1993}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

but it returns:

> 1st AUTHOR, 2nd AUTHOR,... : "Title" [#]

How can I shorten the `\citeauthor` output without any effect to otput of `\printbibliography`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Do you mean the option `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`?

Comment: Thorsten: I thought that my example was minimal enough...

Comment: Marco: I've never heard of them...

Comment: @Crowley: It was too minimal, because it was not working. See my Thorsten's link for more information about MWE and my answer for an example of a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may set option `maxcitenames` to only influence the cites but not the bibliography, e.g.,

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ Author:2001,
  author = {1st AUTHOR and 2nd AUTHOR and 3rd AUTHOR},
  title = {Title}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% option demo for demostration only!
\usepackage[maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\newcommand\foo[1]{\vspace{3ex}% \\[3ex] replaced to avoid "there's no
                            % line to end here" errors
  \footnotesize{From: \citeauthor{#1}: \citetitle{#1} \cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics{fig1}
 \caption{Some text}
 \foo{Author:2001}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: With option `mincitenames=1` it's foolproof.
Thanks for your answer.